# Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 401 Unauthorized for URL

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, router, canactivate

[image]I am trying to implement authGuard for my Routers.  but when I interfere with error codes, the app breaks actually. I don't know how to tackle it. assistance needed.

My AuthGuard

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

    return this._auth.validate()
      .map((isValidated) => {
        if (isValidated && localStorage.getItem('authToken') && this.checkCookie()) {
          return true;
        }
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
        return false;
      });
  }
```

My Auth Service

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  loginStatus;

  constructor(private http: Http, private _apiEndPoint: ApiEndPoint, private router: Router) { }

  validate() {

    return this.http.get(this._apiEndPoint.validate)
      .map(
      (response: Response) => {

        const result = response.json();

        // check authentication status from response
        if (result.authenticated) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      })
    .catch(error => Observable.throw(error));
  }

}
```

I am getting this error, Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 401 Unauthorised for URL.

[image: ScreenShot of my Error]

and when I get that error my page goes all blank.

Comment: this._apiEndPoint.validate is requiring authorization. Did you miss passing token in HTTP header? I am supposing you are using Web API here.

Comment: yes. actually. everything is working fine.I wantonly deleted my cookie sent in my header to check results. how to catch that error response instead of being thrown in console. @wannadream

Comment: this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError); Check details in doc. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#fetch-data

Comment: attached a screenshot

Comment: I tried that. Its not helping. I get a diffrent error..Let me post that too..@wannadream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed by returning observable of false

```
return this._auth.validate()
      .map((isValidated) => {
        if (isValidated && localStorage.getItem('authToken') && this.checkCookie()) {
          return true;
        }
      }).catch(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return Observable.of(false);
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a catch, and catch has to return an observable.

```
validate() {

return this.http.get(this._apiEndPoint.validate)
  .map(
  (response: Response) => {

    const result = response.json();

    // check authentication status from response
    return result.authenticated;
  })
  .catch(error => Observable.throw(error)); // If you want to throw nothing, then return Observable.empty()
}
```

Comment: thanks. I tried that, but getting the same error. I cannot understand why?